# Example request pertaining to fundamental systems of neighborhoood in point set topology

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and $x\in X$
>     **Definition:**  A set $V\subset X$ is a neighborhood of $x$ (in the space $(X,T)$) if there exists a set $U\in T$ such that $x\in U\subset V$ 
>   For each $x\in X$, we denote by $N(x)$ the set of all neighborhoods of $x$ in the space $(X,T)$.  
>     **Definition:**  A set $F\subset N(x)$ is a fundamental system of $x$ if for every $V\in N(x)$ there exists $W\in F$ such that $W\subset V$.  
>   Notice that if $F$ is a fundamental system of $x\in X$, then every set $W\in F$ is  a neighborhhood of $x$.  However, a fundamental system of $x$ does not necessarily contain all the neighborhoods of $x$.

I found the following definition of neighborhood of $x$ and fundamental system of a point $x$ in an old topology text.  I am wondering if someone in the community can give an example illustrating the last sentence of the above block quote.  It states that "every fundamental system of $x$ does not necessarily contain all the neighborhoods of $x$"

My understanding of a fundamental system of a point $x$ is a set which is a family of sets where each set within the family contains a subset which contains $x$. So how can a neighborhood of $x$ which also contains a subset containing $x$ consider not to be in the fundamental system.  Am I missing something.  Thank you in advance.

Edit:  the block quote comes from the text Topology by William W Fairchild and Cassius Ionescu Tulcea.  Apologies for not included the reference the first time.

Comment: Correct the error in the first definition.

Comment: Second definition has minor error.

Comment: @WilliamElliot, I just checked with the text where I got both definitions.  I typed it verbatim.

Comment: Find and correct the mistakes and report an errata to the writer or publisher.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I think both authors have passed away.  I highly doubt W.B.Saunders company will issue a second edition anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

In the real line with usual topology consider $\{(t-\frac 1  n,t+\frac 1 n): n=1,2...\}$. This is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of $t$ but it does  not contain neighborhoods  like $(t-1,t+2)$.

Comment: a set can be a neighborhood of a point but not necessarily be a part of the fundamental system of a point.  Just like any set within a topological space is consider as an open set, but we don't need all the open sets to form a topology.  Is that the correct analogy?

Comment: By definition, the topology is the set of all open sets.  Base or local base need not have all the open sets or open sets with t included.  The use of bases is by limiting the number of open sets, results are easier.

Answer (score 1):

{ U : t in U, U open } is a fundamental system.
It does not include all nhoods of t that are not open.

For t = 1 in R, it does not include the nhood (0,2) $\cup$ {3}.

Nowadays, instead of fundamental systems, local bases are used.

Comment: is the definition of local bases the same as what is called "fundamental system" here?  I thought "fundamental system" is the same as neighborhood system also.  In the end, does it boil down to difference in semantics?

Comment: Bases are collections of open sets.  The union of any collection of sets of a base is open.  No so for fundamental systems.

Comment: is the definition "neighborhood system" still in use, or has it been replaced by the use of "bases". It just seems the concept of base and subbase are much more straightforward.

Comment: I am just wondering also, if bases are as you say are so much nicer to work with, are there any more use for the use of the definition: "fundamental systems"
By the way, I am not sure what is the error you were referring to.  I don't know the subtlety behind these definitions well enough to spot the error.

Comment: Nhoods are more or less obsolete even though they occasionally have a use.  The 1st error is confusing x for t.  The 2nd is T should be t.  Fundamental system does indeed date the text,

Comment: the first error is how the text stated it. The second error is a type entirely my fault.  Thank you for pointing it out.  Also, thank you for the explanations.

Comment: @SethMai neighbourhood systems and fundamental systems (which are like "bases" for them) can be very convenient for local considerations: constructing sequences, or manifolds (which are defined by their local structure) and local properties like like local compactness and local connectedness. A space $X$ is locally connected if each $x \in X$ has a fundamental system consisting of connected sets. Likewise for "local compactness" (though there some weaker notions are also considered regularly). $X$ is regular iff each point has a fundamental system of closed sets. Etc. Quite natural.

Answer (score 1):

Neighbourhoods $N$ of $x$ are sets that contain an open set (a set from $\mathcal{T}$) that contains $x$, or equivalently $x \in \operatorname{int}(N)$.
A fundamental system for $x$ is the analogue of what a local base at $x$ is to set of all open sets that contain $x$. I.e. a subcollection that is "co-initial" in a way: every neighbourhood of $x$ must contain some neighbourhood of the fundamental system at $x$, just like any open set containing $x$ must contain a set from a local base at $x$ (and sets in that local base are themselves open too).

So as a standard example, in a metric space $(X,d)$ all closed balls $D_d(x,r)=\{y \in x: d(x,y) \le r\}$ form a fundamental system at $x$: they are a neighbourhood of $x$ because they contain the open set (by definition of the metric topology) $B_d(x,r) = \{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$ and it is fundamental: let $N$ be any neighbourhood of $x$ in the metric topology. So for some open $O$ with $x \in O$ we have $O \subseteq N$. Then there is some $s>0$ and $y \in X$ such that $x \in B(y,s) \subseteq O$ (as $O$ is a union of open balls) and then the triangle inequality implies that $B_d(x,r) \subseteq B(y,s)$ where $r=s-d(x,y)$ and then we note that $D_d(x,\frac{r}{2})$ (which is the fundamental system) obeys

$$D_d(x,\frac{r}{2}) \subseteq B_d(x,r) \subseteq B(y,s) \subseteq O \subseteq N$$

so $N$ contains a fundamental neighbourhood, as promised. To get a fundamental system that is smaller still we can take

$$\{D_d(x,\frac{1}{n}: n \in \Bbb N\}$$
which works as for any $r>0$ we have some $n$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n}< r$ and so $D_d(x,\frac{1}{n}) \subseteq D_d(x,r)$. So in many cases we can find plenty of neighbourhoods that are not in the fundamental system. E.g. in $\Bbb R$, for $x=0$, $(-1,1)$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ (an open one, even) but is in neither of the fundamental neighbourhood systems I have just defined. And $[-1,1]\cup \{2\}$ is another one.

The fundamental systems cam be a useful notion in cases where we define properties locally: we can just say that $X$ is locally connected iff every point has a fundamental system of connected sets.

Or as another example: $X$ is regular iff every point has a fundamental system of closed sets.

Or $f: X \to Y$ is continuous at $x$ iff for every fundamental system $\mathcal{F}$ for $f(x)$, $\{f^{-1}[F]: F \in \mathcal{F}\} \subseteq \mathcal{N}(x)$, where the latter is the set of neighbourhoods of $x$ as usual (the collection of inverse images need not be fundamental). So we can get nice reformulations and view on basic concepts that way.